# Persisting a network of entities in db via Hibernate/JPA

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two objects, which are referring each other:

```
class User {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="admin")
    List<Group> ownedGroups;
}

class Group {
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "admin_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User admin;
    User admin;
}
```

In the group service layer, there's a method `create` which takes in a group, creates a group, sets that user as the admin of the group, adds the group to the list of `ownedGroups` and saves it to the db:

```
    public void create(String groupName, String username) throws IOException {
        User user = userService.loadByUsername(username);
        Group group = new Group();
        group.setAdmin(user);
        user.addOwnedGroup(group);
        // groupRepository.save(group); 
        // userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

Now I wonder which entity I should save to the db ? user or group ? as one is a new instance and another one is updated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save only group entity as user is already persisted in database. You can retrieve the groups attached to the users from User entity as you have already created the mapping.

And also when you going to retrieve group it will give you the admin user entity too.

```
    public void create(String groupName, String username) throws IOException {
        User user = userService.loadByUsername(username);
        Group group = new Group();
        group.setAdmin(user);
        user.addOwnedGroup(group);
        groupRepository.save(group); 
        //groupRepository.saveAndFlush(group); you can flush to save instantly
    }
```

Comment: when does `user.addOwnedGroup` reflect in the db ? when the group is saved to the db ? Sometimes I grab an entity from the db, make some changes on it, do I need to save it back to the db ? or Spring takes care of that automatically ?

Comment: Yes if you make any changes you have to save it again. You can use Flush to save it instantly.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. Assume that A has one-to-one relation with B, B has the same relation with C. If I make a change on C and B, isn't it enough to just save B ? what if I set CascadeType to `Refresh` or `All`?